# C# to VB.net conversion

Tags: c#-to-vb.net

Could you please convert this two lines of code to VB.net?

```
MembershipUser newUser = Membership.GetUser(reg.UserName);
Guid newUserID=(Guid)newUser.ProviderUserKey;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/ outputs:

```
'reg is CreateUserWizard
Dim newUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(reg.UserName)
Dim newUserID As Guid = DirectCast(newUser.ProviderUserKey, Guid)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
'reg is CreateUserWizard
Dim newUser As MembershipUser = Membership.GetUser(reg.UserName)
Dim newUserID As Guid = DirectCast(newUser.ProviderUserKey, Guid)
```